# How to recover files and then wipe an unbootable Windows 10 drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

I have a SSD with Windows 10 on it installed in a broken laptop so I can't boot into Windows to get the files off and then do a system restore to clear off my data.

I could use tools like dd t recover the files from the drive no problem, but I plan to sell the laptop on as spares or repairs so I don't want to totally format the drive and lose Windows, but I don't want to leave my personal data on there either. Is there a way to recover these files and then perform a system restore for Windows 10 to clear my data off but leave a working Windows 10 install on the drive?
Thanks

Comment: Broken means what is status? If you want the data connect as secondary disk in any windows machine and take the backup.

Comment: Broken as in chips on mobo have died so it won't power on. How do I wipe the files off of the drive (user data etc) from a secondary device?

Comment: Connect your HDD with any other working Windows machine and take back up and wipe it.

Comment: Will that leave the windows 10 installation on the old HDD?

Comment: @tomh1012 - If you wipe it, then SSD is wiped, that means the installation will no longer exist.  I honestly don't understand your question.  I strongly suggest you grab your files, then wipe the SSD, stop trying to worry about keeping Windows 10 (it is trivial to install Windows 10 the installation isn't rquired).

Comment: I'm trying to remove my personal files from the hard drive but leave the windows installation totally intact , like a Windows system restore would do, but because I can't turn on the laptop to get into windows to do this system restore, I was wondering if there was a way to perform a similar action without the use of the laptop